# Error in if (grep( )), argument is of length zero in R

Tags: r

I have seen few already present solution in Stackoverflow but unable to relate that with my problem.

I have writtem this code:

```
for (i in 1: nrow(Yesterday_data)) {
    for (j in 1: nrow(newOP_data))
    if (grep(Yesterday_data$Dimension[i], newOP_data$Advert[j])) {
        Yesterday_data$rate[i] < -newOP_data$Ops_data.Rate[j]
        Yesterday_data$rate_type[i] < -newOP_data$Ops_data.Rate.Type[j]
        Yesterday_data$status[i] < -newOP_data$Ops_data.Status[j]
        Yesterday_data$start_date[i] < -newOP_data$Ops_data.Campaign.Actual.Start.date..MM.DD.YYYY.[j]
        Yesterday_data$end_date[i] < -newOP_data$Ops_data.Campaign.End.date..MM.DD.YYYY.[j]
        Yesterday_data$target[i] < -newOP_data$Ops_data.Delivered.Target..MTD.[j]
        Yesterday_data$daysofcampaign[i] < -newOP_data$Ops_data.Campaign.Duration[j]

        break
    }
}
```

but

> Error in if (grep(Yesterday_data$Dimension[i], newOP_data$Advert[j]))
>   { :    argument is of length zero

I have check both the columns in if,there is no missing value. I am new to R. please help.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for `Yesterday_data` and `newOP_data`? Assuming they're `data.frames`, try `dput(head(Yesterday_data))` etc if it's not sensitive.

Comment: Check if the values of i and j in your loop always remain withing the range

Comment: Use `grepl` instead of `grep`, as `grep` fails the `if` statement when there is no match.

Comment: This is Yerster data-Dimension Impressions Clicks Spends
TIMES OF INDIA 37137813 96824 135773
TIMES OF INDIA 21291379 38394 0
HUFFINGTONPOST 7341579 16577 17809
NAVBHARATTIMES 3199488 7921 0
DIGISMART DIGITAL MEDIA PVT. LTD. 2744721 7912 27692

Comment: @-Akhil Nair  Yesterday data-   Dimension Impressions Clicks Spends,    new op data contains many cols where I have to create new table if Dimension matches with newOP_data 's Advert column.